# Remove concrete string from CSV in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, csv, replace, tags

I got a ruby script which take XML files and create from them CSV. This CSV use semicolons as delimiter -> but, content of XML contains these tags:

```
 - &amp;  
 - &lt;  
 - &gt;
```

And this of course break the structure of CSV file. I need clean it up. This cleaner must be writen in Ruby. I try next code, but this complete destroy the file.

```
#Clean up CSV file 
#Remove: &amp; \&lt; &gt;

file_names = ['terms.csv']

file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  new_contents = text.gsub(/&amp;/, " and ")

  # To merely print the contents of the file, use:
  puts new_contents

  # To write changes to the file, use:
  File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
end

file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  new_contents = text.gsub(/&lt;/, " < ")

  puts new_contents

  File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
end

file_names.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  new_contents = text.gsub(/&gt;/, " > ")

  puts new_contents

  File.open(file_name, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
end
```

I never use Ruby - this is my first contact. Is there better way how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it... I change CSV delimiter from ";" to "#" in FOR cycle which create a CSV file. It is not ideal solution, but it works.

Comment: Why don't you use the CSV core library of Ruby ? The CSV format supports escaping so it isn't a problem to have data with the column delimiter in it. But it will require a real CSV parser for reading it though, most CSV readers fail on that